# ADF Check If Header Row Start with A1

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

In the Azure Data Factory pipeline, if I have an Excel file that I am going to perform data transformation. Is there a way to check if the header row start with row 1 first, if yes, then goes to the next step for data mapping flow, and if not, will return a message note that the data doesn't not start with row 1? Thank you!

I tried with lookup activity, but seems like I have to create a dataset first for the Excel file which is not ideal in my use case.

Comment: 'Is there a way to check if the header row start with row 1 first', How you are going to check this? can you provide a sample data and expected result? and you want use inline dataset only right?

Comment: For example, the first column header name is "ID", then I can check if cell A1 value is "ID", if cell A1 value is not "ID" that means the headers are not in row 1. And yes, inline dataset will be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use First row as header in source options which takes the First row and check the columns names in Conditional split like below.

[image]

If the A1 row is total empty in excel it will take 2nd row as header, then use conditional split and check the column names.

```
equals(columnNames()[1],'Id')
```

[image]

Now, you will get the data which satisfies your condition like below.

[image]

Use your next transformation after this(`check1`). If your header is not the one you want it will go to `check2` and stop the execution.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your answer. I was wondering what if I want to check if the header row start with row 5, can I still use conditional split in this case?

Comment: if the rows before row5 are empty, then first Row as header will read the rows5 directly.

Comment: I think in some of my sample files, the rows before the header row are not blank, is there a workaround with this case? Also in the conditional split check 2, if the header row is the one I want, can I output a warning message instead saying the header row is not row 1?

Comment: we cannot distinguish which is the header if it lies between the rows, so its better to change the data pattern and coming to check2, you can add a derived column and give a the warning message in that and then use another sink with sink cache. Using sink cache we can get the file rows as activity output json by which you can check that in your pipeline after dataflow.

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, I tried with a file starting with row 2, however, I still got a sink output file for check1 but only with headers lik2 c1,c2.c3 etc...I thought if the condition equals(columnNames()[1],'Id') failed, there won't be any output?

Comment: if the columnNames have id, then the condition will succeed. In your case please check what are the columnNames returning in the transformation.

Comment: If the check 1 is checking if the first row has columnname ID, but I have column header in row 2 so I would assume the check1 won't succeed?

Comment: No, it won't work in that way. if you check First row as header, it will take the first row as header and column names contains Id only. So, better to arrange your headers first.